# NCBI BLAST, nr database

Tags: database, blast, ncbi

I am running the command for BLAST :

```
blastp -query /Users/shalini/Desktop/shalini/project/unmodelled_fasta/AAA18895.fasta -outfmt "7 sacc qcovs pident ppos evalue" -db=/Users/shalini/Downloads/nr -out=/Users/shalini/Desktop/shalini/project/blast_resultnr
```

After running for one and half hour, it results in:

```
Error memory mapping:/Users/shalini/Downloads/nr.79.phr openedFilesCount=251 threadID=0 BLAST Database error: Cannot memory map /Users/shalini/Downloads/nr.79.phr. Number of files opened: 251
```

I am working on macOS. Also I have built the database of nr which results in 114 .phr, .pin, .psq and .pog files.

Please help me, if anyone knows.

Comment: It looks like you have a memory issue at 79th file. I had something similar when I tried to build nr db in my computer. The problem solved when I move the database in to a bigger hard disk.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I'm experiencing the same - blastn is using 0.5 GB memory w/ 10GB left unused before failing w/ this error. I also have 20 GB of free disk space, but I don't think disk space availability is the issue